# Select text in HTML JEditor Pane

Tags: java, html, swing

I have a JEditor Pane with HTML content. The HTML content present elements with formatting (`<ul>...</ul>, <br>,` etc.). I would like to allow at users to select textual segments in this content, but keeping the layout (and, consequently, the tags).

I thought to use a span system, but I don't know to keep layout.

For instance ;

```
<p>Bla bla ... bla bla. There are three planes in the airport :</p>
<ul>
<li> A spitfire;</li>
<li> A airbus;</li>
<li> A x15.</li>
</ul>
```

How to only select structure that begins "There are three planes ..." and ends with "X15."?
A simple system with span doesn't  select first tag `<p>` and ending tags (`</li>\n</ul>`). Have you a idea to do that?

I hope be enough clear.

Thank you in advance

Comment: it's not clear what you would like to achieve. Please explain more. Why can't you use setSelectionStart()/setSelectionEnd()?

Comment: I want develop a annotation platform where a user could select textual structure with formatting. This selection will be executed with a drag-and-drop system on a JEditorPane (or other JSwing textual components that accept HTML content).

In fact, I want get HTML content with tags for keeping the layout. I think methods "setSelectionStart()" and "setSelectionEnd()" doesn't return html tags.

Comment: Rectification, methods "setSelectionStart()" and "setSelectionEnd()" return html tags, but 2 problems ; (1) results does not correspond between selection chars (in JEditorPane) and text returned, and (2) for a text selected between `<p> ... </p>`, I want  select the last `</p>` (easy, I think), but too first `</p>` (more difficult).